# I want to set dynamic data-pie percentage value using Jquery. Here is code below?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set dynamic data-pie percentage value using Jquery. Here is code below?? I just want to change value dynamic using JQuery

```
<div class="pie" id="lecture-chart" data-pie='{ "speed": 30, "percent": 71, "colorSlice": "#6cb64f", "colorCircle": "#f1f1f1", "round": true }'></div>
```

Comment: Please show us the code for your latest attempt and where you got stuck.

Comment: <div class="pie" id="lecture-chart" data-pie='{ "speed": 30, "percent": 71, "colorSlice": "#6cb64f", "colorCircle": "#f1f1f1", "round": true }'>
                         <div class="progress-title" style="margin-right: 18px;"> 
                            <h4 id="lectures_viewed">0</h4>
                            <p>Lecture Viewed</p>
                         </div>
                      </div>

Comment: I don't see any javascript or jquery here. Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Here i set percentage 71% as you can see it above..  I just want to get idea of Javascript or JQuery For example i select course dropdown i can calculate using AJAX and JQuery but I'm confused how to overwrite percentage using JQuery ... HTML code is in front of you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please take a while and read [ask] with [mre]. Good luck

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, your question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should convert the value of data-pie to JSON then you set the value of percentage. something like:

```
function updatePercentageValue(value){
    var pieValueString = $("#lecture-chart").data("pie");
    var pieValueObj = JSON.parse(pieValueString);
    pieValueObj["percent"] = value;
    $("#lecture-chart").data("pie", JSON.stringify(pieValueObj))
}
```

Comment: var pieValueString = $("#lecture-chart").data("pie"); 
alert(JSON.stringify(pieValueString.percent));    From this way I'm getting value of percentage from but i want to assign value to data pie using JQuery